# Como converter um buffer em um tipo imagem usando react e typescript

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, react, typescript

Estou com problemas ao mostrar uma imagem trazida do banco de dados.

**-> Primeiro vou mostrar como essa imagem está sendo armazenada:**

Aqui eu faço a importação e envio dela pro backend

```
import profile_default_image from "../../../other/imgs/profile_default_image.png";
resRegister = await register(user_name, user_email, user_password, profile_default_image);
```

**profile_default_image** gera um tipo **string** com valor = **/static/media/profile_default_image.a9136072d073801df253.png**

Esse valor é armazenado no banco de dados **MYSQL** em um campo tipo **BLOB**.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Abaixo** está o valor do **profileImage** de um registro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**-> Agora vou mostrar o que está acontecendo no front**

```
  const [profileImage, setProfileImage] = useState("teste");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUser() {
      if (id) {
        const res = await apiFindUserById(id);
        const base64Flag = "data:image/jpeg;base64,";
        const b64Image = await Buffer.from(res.data.profileImage.data).toString("base64");
        setProfileImage(base64Flag + b64Image);
      }
    }

    getUser();
  }, []);
```

**res.data** retorna o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Abaixo** eu tento colocar a imagem na tela

```
      <div>
        <img style={{ width: 200, height: 200, }}
          src={profileImage}
          alt="test"
        />
      </div>
```

Mas o único resultado que eu tenho é isso:
[image: ![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dei um console.log em **profileImage** e ele retornou o valor de:

> data:image/jpeg;base64,L3N0YXRpYy9tZWRpYS9wcm9maWxlX2RlZmF1bHRfaW1hZ2UuYTkxMzYwNzJkMDczODAxZGYyNTMucG5n

Que basicamente é uma imagem em branco.

Tentei outra forma de fazer igual achei aqui no stackoverflow

```
  const [profileImage, setProfileImage] = useState("teste");

  const arrayBufferToBase64 = (buffer: any) => {
    let binary = "";
    let bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    let len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return window.btoa(binary);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUser() {
      if (id) {
        const res = await apiFindUserById(id);
        const imageStr = await arrayBufferToBase64(res.data.profileImage.data);
        const base64Flag = "data:image/jpeg;base64,";
        setProfileImage(base64Flag + imageStr);
        console.log(profileImage);
      }
    }

    getUser();
  }, []);
```

Obtive o mesmo resultado.

A imagem original é um avatar default de usuário.

Pode ser que o problema esteja até mesmo na hora que estou armazenando essa imagem no banco de dados, alguém pode me ajudar? Estou muito perdido.

Answer (score -3):

Conforme sua pergunta, você está obtendo um valor `string` e armazenando-o no BD como se fosse um valor binário.

O equívoco foi tentar usar esse valor como se fosse uma imagem ao jogá-lo em um *data URI*.

Se você pegar o valor `L3N0YXRpYy9tZWRpYS9wcm9maWxlX2RlZmF1bHRfaW1hZ2UuYTkxMzYwNzJkMDczODAxZGYyNTMucG5n` e [converter para texto](https://www.base64decode.org/), o resultado é `/static/media/profile_default_image.a9136072d073801df253.png`. Para ser aceito como um *data URI* válido de imagem, o conteúdo desse buffer deveria ser os dados binários completos da imagem, não o caminho até ela no disco.

Para o seu primeiro exemplo funcionar, converta o buffer para texto normal (UTF-8) e remova o prefixo do *data URI*:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUser() {
      if (id) {
        const res = await apiFindUserById(id);
        const imagePath = await Buffer.from(res.data.profileImage.data).toString();
        setProfileImage(imagePath);
      }
    }

    getUser();
  }, []);
```

Agora se a sua intenção é obter o conteúdo binário do arquivo de imagem como um `Buffer` para salvar depois no banco de dados, use o método [`readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlereadfileoptions) que vem do módulo nativo `fs/promises`:

```
import fs from 'fs/promises';
import profile_default_image from "../../../other/imgs/profile_default_image.png";

//...

const profile_default_image_buffer = await fs.readFile(profile_default_image);
```